# Proper method of using std::chrono

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

While I realize this is probably one of many identical questions, I can't seem to figure out how to properly use std::chrono. This is the solution I cobbled together.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;

float startTime;

float getCurrentTime();

int main () {
    startTime = getCurrentTime();
    std::cout << "Start Time: " << startTime << "\n";

    while(true) {
        std::cout << getCurrentTime() - startTime << "\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

float getCurrentTime() {
    auto now = Time::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() / 1000;
}
```

For some reason, this only ever returns integer values as the difference, which increments upwards at rate of 1 per second, but starting from an arbitrary, often negative, value.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The result of two integral arguments divided by each other is an integral value.

Comment: @SergeyA That fixed the result not being a float, but it still starts at the wrong number.

Comment: `return std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() / 1000.0F;`

Comment: @Arkathorn You should get better precision if you calculate the difference on `std::chrono::time_point`s.

Comment: Instead of  dividing by `1000` you should returns a custom second duration using a floating point representation.

Comment: Just something to play with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/231e117a15ed8729

Answer (score 23):

- Don't escape the chrono type system until you absolutely have to.  That means don't use `.count()` except for I/O or interacting with legacy API.

This translates to:  Don't use `float` as time_point.

- Don't bother with `high_resolution_clock`.  This is always a typedef to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.  For more portable code, choose one of the latter.

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using Time = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
```

To start, you're going to need a duration with a representation of `float` and the units of `seconds`.  This is how you do that:

```
using float_sec = std::chrono::duration<float>;
```

Next you need a `time_point` which uses `Time` as the clock, and `float_sec` as its duration:

```
using float_time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Time, float_sec>;
```

Now your `getCurrentTime()` can just return `Time::now()`.  No fuss, no muss:

```
float_time_point
getCurrentTime() {
    return Time::now();
}
```

Your `main`, because it has to do the I/O, is responsible for unpacking the chrono types into scalars so that it can print them:

```
int main () {
    auto startTime = getCurrentTime();
    std::cout << "Start Time: " << startTime.time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";

    while(true) {
        std::cout << (getCurrentTime() - startTime).count() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code `getCurrentTime().time_since_epoch().count()` will always return the same value. Any idea why?

Comment: @Arkathorn: On my system this returns the number of floating point seconds since the computer booted.  It changes as expected each time I run the program.  If I call it twice in a row, it will appear to have the same value because it prints out only to an accuracy of a tenth a second.  What platform are you on?

Comment: Windows 10. It always returns `1.46119e+012`.

Comment: (Actually, the value is `1.4612e+009`)

Comment: (Realizes that platform might not necessarily be OS)
I'm using MinGW.

Comment: @Arkathorn:  Ok.  You're using either `system_clock` or `high_resolution_clock` which is an alias to `system_clock` on Windows.  This is returning the number of seconds since New Years 1970, which is currently about 1.4 billion.  If you run it again in a day or so (100,000 seconds), you'll see a change in the least significant digit of your output.

Comment: @Arkathorn:  `float` doesn't have the precision you're looking for (tracking fractions among billions of seconds).  You'll either need to switch to `steady_clock` to get a lower number of seconds since epoch, or switch to `double` to get the extra precision.

Comment: The distance between two adjacent float values on the order of 1.4e+9 is 128 (two minutes 8 seconds).  The distance between two adjacent double values in this range is only about 200ns.

Answer (score 5):

This program does a similar thing. Hopefully it shows some of the capabilities (and methodology) of std::chrono:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    namespace chrono = std::chrono;
    using clock_type = chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    auto start = clock_type::now();

    for(;;) {
        auto first = clock_type::now();

        // note use of literal - this is c++14
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

        // c++11 would be this:
        //        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

        auto last = clock_type::now();
        auto interval = last - first;
        auto total = last - start;

        // integer cast
        std::cout << "we just slept for " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(interval).count() << "ms\n";

        // another integer cast
        std::cout << "also known as " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(interval).count() << "ns\n";

        // floating point cast
        using seconds_fp = chrono::duration<double, chrono::seconds::period>;
        std::cout << "which is " << chrono::duration_cast<seconds_fp>(interval).count() << " seconds\n";

        std::cout << "  total time wasted: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(total).count() << "ms\n";
        std::cout << "         in seconds: " << chrono::duration_cast<seconds_fp>(total).count() << "s\n";


        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
we just slept for 503ms
also known as 503144616ns
which is 0.503145 seconds
  total time wasted: 503ms
         in seconds: 0.503145s

we just slept for 500ms
also known as 500799185ns
which is 0.500799 seconds
  total time wasted: 1004ms
         in seconds: 1.00405s

we just slept for 505ms
also known as 505114589ns
which is 0.505115 seconds
  total time wasted: 1509ms
         in seconds: 1.50923s

we just slept for 502ms
also known as 502478275ns
which is 0.502478 seconds
  total time wasted: 2011ms
         in seconds: 2.01183s
```